# Cannot access value of the object returned when subscribe() is called in Typescript (Angular 8)

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api

Here is where I am generating the 6 digit OTP in Visual Studio (Web API)

```
        static int otp; 

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] PhoneNum ph)
        {
            try
            {
                int otpValue = new Random().Next(100000, 999999);
                otp = otpValue;
...
```

I am returning the OTP class object using IHttpActionResult

```
    [Route("getotpsession")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOTPSession()
    {
        OTPClass otp_curr = new OTPClass();
        otp_curr.current_otp = otp.ToString();
        return Ok(otp_curr);
    }
```

In Angular I have tried getting this object using subscribe()

```
    getSessionOTP(){
    this.session_otp = this.otpservice.getOTP().subscribe((data)=> {this.session_otp = data; console.log(this.session_otp)}) 

    alert(this.session_otp)
  }
```

**The Problem is -**

1. I am getting the alert as [object Object]
2. console.log(this.session_otp) is giving me {current_otp:"345262"} -- This means, object is being fetched

How do I fetch the OTP from the object being returned? (like in console.log)
I have tried many solutions, most including the JSON.stringify() solution. None is working.

Please Help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an Observable/http/async call in angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43055706/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-observable-http-async-call-in-angular)

Comment: R. Richards, no, that didn't. However the below solution worked....Anyway, thank you for your time. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here session_otp is an object, You need to access the `current_otp` property from object.

But in your code `alert` is out side of subscription.

Try this code,

```js
getSessionOTP(){
    this.session_subscription = 
    this.otpservice.getOTP()
      .subscribe((data)=> {
          this.session_otp = data;
          console.log(this.session_otp);
          alert(this.session_otp.current_otp);
       });
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the object expecting it to be its property. Try something like this:

```
getSessionOTP(){
  this.session_otp = this.otpservice.getOTP().subscribe((data)=> {
    this.session_otp = data.current_otp; console.log(this.session_otp)
    alert(this.session_otp)
  })    
}
```

Take note, I am now using the `current_otp` property rather than the whole object.

Comment: Im getting "Property 'current_otp' does not exist on type 'Object'" as an error, since current_otp is present in Visual Studio's OTPClass.cs.

Comment: Then try `data['current_otp']` that will allow you to access the property even if it isn't typed.